# What is the maximum current can pass in BQ40Z50R2 (fuel gauge IC?)

Tags: current, fuel-gauge

I am unable to find the maximum current this fuel gauge IC can pass from its [datasheet.](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sluscs4)

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet doesn't say because the maximum current would depend on which FETs you use with it.

The datasheet tells you the capacity range (100mA to 29Ah) but it doesn't say anything about the current.

Comment: ,thanks for your response sir,but in datasheet,not specific FET is mentioned.

Comment: The maximum current depends on which FET **you** decide to use in your circuit.

Comment: ok,thank you sir